# Unable to delete the 'first' records from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete records in my table customer where period is monthly (M) and weekly (W). However using the below code, no data is being deleted.

I have also try using begin statement but still this does not work.

Can we use @period IN?? Any advise or help on my below code please?

Thank you

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(1)
IF @Period IN ('M','W')

BEGIN

IF EXISTS
(
SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM Customer WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IDNumber = '2511' AND 
Period = @Period
)

BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Customer WHERE IDNumber = '2511' AND Period = @Period
END

END
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP()` **without** an explicit `ORDER BY` is pointless - you're getting the "first" row - ordered by what?? If you don't specify anything, you'll just get *one, arbitrary row" - there's no telling what this is the "first" for ...... Also: inside a `IF EXISTS()`, there's no point in using a `TOP (1)` since no actual data is fetched and returned - the `IF EXISTS` **only** returns "true" or "false" as to whether at least one row matching the `WHERE` criteria exists....

Comment: There's little point in using `exists` to check for rows that may be deleted without using a transaction around the operations, simply attempt the `delete` and, if you need to know what happened, check `@@RowCount` or add an `output` clause. And `nolock` is rarely the answer, whatever the question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(1)= '?';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND Period = @Period
      AND(@Period = 'M' OR @Period = 'W');
```

Or if you want to delete all rows where `IDNumber = '2511'` and both `'W'` and `'M'`, then you can do like

```
DELETE FROM Cutomer
WHERE IDNumber = '2511'
      AND 
      (Period = 'M' OR Period = 'W');-- Period IN('M', 'W');
```

---

Since you want to delete both, you need to change the length of your variable from `1` to `3`, then you can use **[`LEFT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`RIGHT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions as

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3) = 'M,W';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      (Period = LEFT(@Period, 1) OR Period = RIGHT(@Period, 1));
```

Or using **[`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** operator as

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3)='M,W';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      ',' + @Period + ',' LIKE '%,' + Period + ',%';
```

If you really want to use `IN()` operator then you have three choices:

1- Using a **[`common table expression (CTE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3)='M,W';

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT LEFT(@Period, 1) Val
  UNION
  SELECT RIGHT(@Period, 1)
)
DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      Period IN(SELECT * FROM CTE);
```

-2 Using a **[`SubQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017)**

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3)='M,W';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      Period IN(
                 SELECT LEFT(@Period, 1)
                 UNION
                 SELECT RIGHT(@Period, 1)
               );
```

3- Using **[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function (or your own string splitter function)

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3)='M,W';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      Period IN(
                 SELECT Value
                 FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Period, ',')
               );
```

---

*Conclustion:*

Looking to **[`IN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** operator

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

So, when you poss your variable to `IN()` operator, it doesn't do what you expect it to do, cause your variable is a *string*, not a *subquery* or a *list* neither. That's why the following query won't delete any row.

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(3)='M,W';

DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE IDNumber = '2511' 
      AND 
      Period IN(@Period);
```

**[Here is a live demo for those queries](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8c9e93b882976169d0216bd2114719b)**

Comment: can't we use the declare period for the deletion?

Comment: @user3687828 Yes we can.

Comment: for the DECLARE @Period CHAR(1)= '?';  I need to delete for period in W and M

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you have not assigned a value to `@Period`.  Presumably, your intention is something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1
           FROM Customer 
           WHERE IDNumber = '2511' AND Period IN ('M', 'W')
          )
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Customer
        WHERE IDNumber = '2511' AND Period IN ('M', 'W');
END;
```

This deletes all matching rows in `Customers`, so the `IF` is unnecessary.  A simple delete with no conditions does the same thing:

```
DELETE FROM Customer
    WHERE IDNumber = '2511' AND Period IN ('M', 'W');
```

If you want to delete only one matching row:

```
DELETE c FROM 
    FROM (SELECT TOP (1) c.*
          FROM Customer c
          WHERE c.IDNumber = '2511' AND c.Period IN ('M', 'W')
         );
```

I would advise you to forget about `@period` until you understand how to do the `DELETE` that you really want.